# Is it possible to define a forced_root_block for each instance of a multi-instance tinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I currently looking for a way to setup each tinymce instance on a single page to use a different forced_root_block element. 
For instance: I render 3 instances on my page. The first one should be h1 the second h2 and the third p.

As I have found in the tinymce docs, I can use the forced_root_block while init() the tinymce. But if I initialize as below, I got h1 as root-tag for all instances.

Is there a way to define this parameter for each single instance? For example within the setup-callback?

Thanks for your help.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    //...
    mode: 'textareas',
    editor_selector: 'article_editor',
    content_css: '/editorcss/',
    forced_root_block: 'h1',
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for me.
It is possible to register a callback-function to the setup-parameter. This is called one-time for each instance of the tinymce. 
Within this callback it is possible to override the editor.settings. So I just read the block attributes from my elements and override these information in the settings.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    //...
    mode: 'textareas',
    editor_selector: 'article_editor',
    setup: function(ed) {
        /**
        * We are looking for textareas != basetext and setup their block-tag and attributes
        **/
        var block_type  = $('#' + ed.id).data('block-type');
        var block_class = $('#' + ed.id).data('block-class');
        var block_style = $('#' + ed.id).data('block-style');

        if (block_type != null) {
            ed.settings.forced_root_block = block_type;
            ed.settings.forced_root_block_attrs = {
                'class': block_class ? block_class : '',
                'style': block_style ? block_style : ''
            }
        }
   //...
```